# How to test a router-link?

Tags: vue.js, testing, vuejs3, vite, vitest

I'm trying to test this component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  label: string
  link: string
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <router-link
    :to="link"
    class="block px-6 py-3 hover:no-underline hover:bg-gray-200 transition"
    data-test="link">
    <service-translator :localeIndex="label" plainText />
  </router-link>
</template>
```

but when I simulate a click event on the `router-link`, the `router` doesn't seem to push to the expected route.

test:

```
import { DOMWrapper, mount, VueWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest'
import ServiceTranslator from 'service-translator-component/components/broc-translate-vue3.vue'
import { i18n } from '@t/test-utils/testUtils'
import { CustomerMasterNavigationLink } from '@t/test-declarations'
import CustomerMasterNavigationLinkComponent from '@/components/customer/customer-master-navigation-link.vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    { path: '/customer/:client/:number', name: 'customer-client-number' },
  ],
})

describe('test customer-master-navigation-link.vue', () => {
  let wrapper: VueWrapper<CustomerMasterNavigationLink>

  beforeEach(async () => {
    wrapper = mount(CustomerMasterNavigationLinkComponent, {
      props: {
        label: 'master_data',
        link: '/customer/new/123',
      },
      global: {
        components: {
          'service-translator': ServiceTranslator,
        },
        plugins: [i18n, router],
      },
      router,
    })
  })

  it('calls link', async () => {
    const link: DOMWrapper<HTMLDivElement> = wrapper.find('[data-test="link"]')

    await link.trigger('click')

    console.log(router)
  })
})
```

output:

```
{
  currentRoute: RefImpl {
    __v_isShallow: true,
    dep: Set(2) { [ReactiveEffect], [ReactiveEffect], w: 0, n: 0 },
    __v_isRef: true,
    _rawValue: {
      path: '/',
      name: undefined,
      params: {},
      query: {},
      hash: '',
      fullPath: '/',
      matched: [],
      meta: {},
      redirectedFrom: undefined
    },
    _value: {
      path: '/',
      name: undefined,
      params: {},
      query: {},
      hash: '',
      fullPath: '/',
      matched: [],
      meta: {},
      redirectedFrom: undefined
    }
  },
  listening: true,
  addRoute: [Function: addRoute],
  removeRoute: [Function: removeRoute],
  hasRoute: [Function: hasRoute],
  getRoutes: [Function: getRoutes],
  resolve: [Function: resolve],
  options: {
    history: {
      location: [Getter],
      base: '',
      go: [Function: go],
      createHref: [Function: bound createHref],
      state: [Getter],
      push: [Function: push],
      replace: [Function: replace],
      pauseListeners: [Function: pauseListeners],
      listen: [Function: listen],
      destroy: [Function: destroy]
    },
    routes: [ [Object] ]
  },
  push: [Function: push],
  replace: [Function: replace],
  go: [Function: go],
  back: [Function: back],
  forward: [Function: forward],
  beforeEach: [Function: add],
  beforeResolve: [Function: add],
  afterEach: [Function: add],
  onError: [Function: add],
  isReady: [Function: isReady],
```

I've tested the `router-mock` by sending a `push` event, which works as expected so what's not working here?